# Chrome Print PDF and CSS transform broken

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf-generation

I'm using Chrome headless to generate a PDF : everything works well until some of the DIVs are containing the following CSS transform :

```
transform-origin: 0px 0px;
transform: scale(0.64);
```

Visually everything looks good in the browser : the content of the DIVs are properly scaled down but when generating (Chrome headless) the PDF (and even when printing using the browser printing feature) some of the DIVs are wrongly placed and scaled : not all of them and this depends on the actual content of the DIVs. Sometimes, the DIVs seems to be scaled once more vertically, sometimes both the X and Y axes are scaled down...

I know it's difficult to reply without seeing the page itself - I'm still working on generating a very small page reproducing the issue - but is there anything I should be aware when using those CSS transform and generating a PDF ?

Note : the same page is fine when *printed* in Firefox but I need to use Chrome for its headless support.